# How to get likes of facebook friends using facebook graph api in python

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

For a web application, I need to get the likes of other friends and am not sure how. I already have the following code (where token is my access code):

```
token = 'CAAHE.......'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
print(profile)
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]
```

which gives me a list of my friends. Is there a way to get the likes of each friend? Also, is there a way to generate an access code of a user within the javascript of the website? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get the likes of friends. Friend permissions are deprecated - not sure if it was ever possible to get the friend likes though. Would be a pretty large privacy issue.

You can only get the friends who authorized your App too, and you can only get some basic data like name and (App Scoped) Facebook ID.